# migrating Flex Air application to Web application error not able to import flash.data

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5, mxml

I am trying to migrate Flash Air application to web. For that I have created a new project with Application type "Web".

After that I copied the code to the new application. Now while compiling I am getting error on following lines:

```
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLMode;
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.filesystem.File;
public class CDatabase extends SQLConnection
{
   . . .
```

And the issue is that actionscript is not recognizing data.* and filesystem packages.

I do not find anywhere mentioned that we can not use these classes in Web applications. Is there any restriction on usage of these classes in Web application, if yes then what is the substitute?

Comment: see the official documentation for example: [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) , you can see whether it's available for flash player at the "Platforms:" label

Comment: The link is mentioning Air1.0 in runtime :( Does it mean, I can not use sqlite and sound files in my web version?

Comment: You can, but you have to find a different way, not using these classes.

Comment: Those APIs are for AIR only, you would need to convert to using a server-based database (via Blaze, PHP, etc... )... There are large number of resources available that show how to use MySql/MariaDB/... with Flash. Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks Sushi, I will explore php option. Now my major worry is I am using synchronous db connection and HTTP is going to be asynchronous, so I will need to do much larger changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not find anywhere mentioned that we can not use these classes in
>   Web applications. Is there any restriction on usage of these classes
>   in Web application

Yes, the [documentation for `SQLConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html) says so:

> **Runtime Versions:**     AIR 1.0

You'll also see the AIR icon shown for all APIs that are only available in AIR: [image]

> if yes then what is the substitute?

There is no direct equivalent to `SQLConnection` and `File` in a Web application, but you have some options to substitute:

- Use [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to store client-side data.
- Use [`FileReference`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) to allow the user to save and load local files.
- Use [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to communicate with a server-side database, for example [PHP and MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp).
- Use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to interact with [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (which has [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)).